# PIL '1' conversion saving as 'L'

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm working on converting jpgs to pure black and white, 1-bit depth images. After converting them using '1', the bit depth is staying as 8, and when I immediately open it again it shows it as a 'L' mode.

```
picture=Image.open("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/1592692.jpg")
picture=picture.convert("1")
picture.mode
'1'
picture.save("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/1592692-1-.jpg")
picture=Image.open("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/1592692-1-.jpg")
picture.mode
'L'
```

Any ideas what's causing this or am I missing a step?

Comment: The JPEG file format intrinsically has a fixed bit-depth of 8. As soon as you save your image as a JPEG, there's no going back. Try saving it as a BMP instead.

Comment: @PaulM. That explains it and using the BMP file seems be what I needed to do. Thank you! I'd pin this as the answer if I could

Comment: Personally, I would avoid BMP if possible. It is dated, poorly specified, inflexible and uncompressed. IMHO, you would do better with PNG every day of the week.